# Send JSON data with Guzzle

Tags: php, httpclient, guzzle

I have got the following cURL command that is running expectedly:

```
curl -X POST
                        -H "Content-Type: application/json"
                        -d '{"duplicateEntitiesIds": [21,31,41]}'
                       {URL}:3003/v1/entities/5/merge
```

And I am trying to replicate that with Guzzle, which however fails, returning a 400 status code:

```
 $request   = $httpClient->post('{URL}:3003/v1/entities/'.$mainEntityId.'/merge',
                                       ['json' =>
                                                 ['duplicateEntitiesIds' => $duplEntitiesIdsToArray]
                                       ]
                                      );
 $response   = $request->send();
```

I have tried to change my post body , but it keeps failing. Any ideas would be appreciated.

**NOTE**

The data should be sent in the following format:

```
{"duplicateEntitiesId": [2,3,4]}
```

Comment: What do var dumps for `$mainEntityId` and `$duplEntitiesIdsToArray` look like?

Comment: did you try hardcoded {"duplicateEntitiesId": [2,3,4]} ? if it works you know that $duplEntitiesIdsToArray have wrong values

Comment: @MikeBrant mainEntityId is the expecting one, and $duplEntitiesIdsToArray is ["2616"] (the correct id) .

Comment: Is it string `"2616"` in the array?  It looks like in your cURL example, you have an array of integers.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes, it is string. Should be something obvious that I am missing.

Comment: @zod I have entered this, but still no luck: ['body' => '{"duplicateEntitiesIds": [2,3,4]}'

Comment: did you try any http client app and test it ? try this .. may be you get specific error...not sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040436/guzzle-handle-400-bad-request

Comment: @zod Yes, I am using Guzzle.