# PHP Guzzle Client error response/Bad Request 400 Google OAuth2 Token

Tags: php, oauth, google-plus, guzzle, bad-request

Guzzle Request

```
try {
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?';

    $client = new Client();
    $request = $client->createRequest('GET', $url);

    $query = $request->getQuery();
    $query['access_token'] = $access_token;

    $response = $client->send($request);

    $json = $response->json();

    if(!empty($json) && !isset($json['error'])) {
        return ($json['audience']==GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
    }

} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Guzzle Response

```
Client error response
[status code] 400
[reason phrase] Bad Request
[url] https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxx
```

Simple CURL Request

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxx';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //disable SSL check
$json_response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$response = json_decode($json_response);
return $response;
```

Simple CURL Response

```
stdClass Object
(
    [issued_to] => xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
    [audience] => xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
    [user_id] => xxx
    [scope] => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
    [expires_in] => 3581
    [access_type] => offline
)
```

I can't figure out whats I am doing wrong with Guzzle, as you can see I got successful result using CURL but got Bad Request error on Guzzle....Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I figure out guzzle is returning actual response when response code is 200/OK, otherwise its returning guzzle exception now I can't figure out how to get the actual response in case of error?

Comment: in guzzle ,this type of error occurs when your `url` is invalid.have you tested url in browser?

Comment: Yes as I said same details i.e. url and credentials are working fine through cURL but got error using guzzle.

Comment: Same issue here and only with Guzzle.

Comment: Same issue too with Guzzle (v3.9) oauth2 request

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution use `RequestException` instead of `Exception`

```
try {
  //Google oAuth2 Code   
} catch(RequestException $e) {
  $response = $e->getResponse()->json(); //Get error response body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to set exceptions = false when configuring guzzle. See a similar answer here: [Guzzle: handle 400 bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040436/guzzle-handle-400-bad-request?newreg=9471dd3af3be4a00a685dd239c3cf039)

```
$guzzle_config = array(
    'defaults' => array(
        'debug' => false,
        'exceptions' => false
        )
    );
```