# Uploaded file opened using fopen error in guzzle json_encode error: Type is not supported

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, guzzle

I cannot attach the uploaded file. I see that fopen($image->getPathname(),'r') returns not convertible json data type making guzzle return error json_encode error: Type is not supported. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

```
stream resource @586 ▼
    timed_out: false
    blocked: true
    eof: false
    wrapper_type: "plainfile"
    stream_type: "STDIO"
    mode: "r"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: true
    uri: "\Temp\php2D41.tmp"
    options: []


//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

if($request->hasFile('imgInp1'))
   {
    foreach(request('imgInp1') as $image)
    {
      $message = Http::post('https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/message_attachments?access_token='.$access_token, 
                                [
                                    'headers' => [
                                        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                                    ],
                                    'multipart' => [
                                        'name'         => 'image',
                                        'image_path'   => $image->getPathname(),
                                        'image_mime'   => $image->getmimeType(),
                                        'image_org'    => $image->getClientOriginalName(),
                                        'contents'     => fopen($image->getPathname(), 'r'),
                                    ],
                                    'message'=>[
                                        'attachment' => [
                                            'type' => 'image',
                                            'payload' => [
                                                "is_reusable"=> true,
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need an `attachment` array on a multipart post?

Comment: also the keys used in multipart are only 4, name, contents,header,filename

Comment: I guess you are using api listed on this site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api/, you are using multipart it will send data as multipart/form-data, ** error** you are mixing syntax of wrapper httpclient with using guzzle directly, ** error** if you are using multipart then app data goes in multipart you are separating it with message key

Comment: Yes im trying to translate Upload from File curl -F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}' 
  -F 'filedata=@/tmp/shirt.png;type=image/png' to http client/guzzle. My error was Incorrect number of files uploaded. I think I am not attaching the image file correctly...I cannot seem to make the fopen work for json encode...I already changed content-type to 'application/json'

Comment: What made you think that a file upload via guzzle would work by passing a file _pointer_ as parameter? I am guessing this should much rather be the actual file _content_ passed at this point, so a quick way to read that at this point would be `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 0):

From the url you used this is the curl request provided in facebook [api_guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api/)

```
curl  \
  -F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}' \
  -F 'filedata=@/tmp/shirt.png;type=image/png' \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/message_attachments?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

This is what -F means in curl

> -F, --form <name=content>
>  (HTTP SMTP IMAP) For HTTP protocol family, this lets  curl  emu‐
> late  a  filled-in  form  in which a user has pressed the submit
> button. This causes curl to POST  data  using  the  Content-Type
> multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.

(Source: `man curl`)

By interpreting second line of curl,

> You  can  also  tell  curl  what  Content-Type  to  use by using
> 'type=', in a manner similar to:
> curl -F "web=@index.html;type=text/html" example.com
> or
> curl -F "name=daniel;type=text/foo" example.com

So it tells that you need multipart/form-data.

I am using guzzle directly inplace of using HttpClient(comes by default in laravel, comfirm from composer.json). Also I suggest to use try catch block as it is not necessary that it will always be 200 response.

```
$message["attachment"] = [
        "type" => "image",
        "payload"=> ["is_reusable"=>true]
    ];

try{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    if(file_exists($image)){ // or can use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::exists($image)
        $request = $client->post( 'https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/message_attachments?access_token='.$access_token, [
            // 'headers' => [],  //if you want to add some
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'message',
                    'contents' => json_encode($message),
                ],
                [
                    'Content-type' => $image->getmimeType(),
                    'name'     => 'filedata',
                    'contents' => fopen($image->getPathname(), 'r'),
                ]
            ]
        ]);
        if ($request->getStatusCode() == 200) {
             $response = json_decode($request->getBody(),true);
             //perform your action with $response 
        } 
    }else{
        throw new \Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException();
    }
}catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e){
    // see this answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658283/catching-exceptions-from-guzzle/64603614#64603614 
    // you can catch here 400 response errors and 500 response errors
    // see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040436/guzzle-handle-400-bad-request/25040600
}catch(Exception $e){
    //catch other errors
}
```

Comment: you can do this with HTTP class as well (it is basically wrapper class for guzzlehttp), but I am more used to using guzzle, I can post HTTP  class answer as well but I would prefer if you use it first

Comment: also no need to add `'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'` as if you used multipart constant of guzzle in $options, Content-Type' is always 'multipart/form-data' whether you like it or not

Comment: Managed to make it work after hours of understanding the code. I was so confused with http client and guzzle. Will use guzzle first and learn how to use it more. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I really agree guzzle has only a short docs & looks hard for someone using it new, so did it work or not, I think the above solution should work it is the similar to the curl request in their docs