# Catch Guzzle exceptions on connections refused

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am using Guzzle with the following code:

```php
try {
    $client = new Client();
    $result = $client->get("http://{$request->ES_HOST}:{$request->ES_PORT}", [
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
            'auth' => [$request->ES_LOGIN, $request->ES_PASSWORD],
            'allow_redirects' => false,
        ]);
    $response['status'] = $result->getStatusCode();
    $response['message'] = json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents());
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    $response['status'] = $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

And it works well however when an user gives the wrong URL for guzzle to process it instead of getting catched in `RequestException` it gives an 500 error in the server and returns a regular `Exception` with the message of `cURL error 7: Failed to connect to [host] port [port]: Connection refused`. Hoe can I make it so that I can catch the error and status code as well to return to the user?

Comment: can you remove try-catch block and check inside logs what kind of exception was thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having tried your code, it seems to be throwing an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException`, so change the catch to

```
} catch (ConnectException $e) {
    $response['status'] = 'Connect Exception';
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

( Adding the appropriate use statement...

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
```

)

Also noticed that it doesn't have `$e->getResponse()->getStatusCode()`, which is why I've just set it to a fixed string.

Comment: Same result, as RequestException already has ConnectException in. https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#exceptions

Comment: @MathiasHillmann Interesting as the source at https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Exception/ConnectException.php has `class ConnectException extends TransferException`

Comment: After messing with the code it seems you are correct and the docs are incorrect (?), ConnectException does catch it, however I need the status code of the request.

Comment: @MathiasHillmann, what status code?  The connection failed and so there is not status.

Comment: if you only want to catch RequestException, then once in catch use `$e->hasResponse()` if it is false, then no connection thus no status code & no `getResponse()` if true then log the `getResponse()` and `getStatusCode()`

Comment: @bhucho `Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException::hasResponse()`

Comment: @NigelRen Connection refused is one of the outcomes of this request, I need to return the status code since this is for a form that checks connection for an external api/token, and the outcomes can be statuses 403, 401, 200 or Connection Refused (404 more or less).

Comment: I managed to use your `ConnectException` and use `RequestException` by checking which instanceof the exception is related, and build a response using that check, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: you can send 502 bad gateway it is close but not as close to no connection, also see this answer for how to use hasResponse() https://stackoverflow.com/a/25040600/10958249

Answer (score 0):

Since Guzzle has so many Exceptions, i ended up checking which type of exception that guzzle has thrown and constructing a response accordingly:

```php
try {
    $client = new Client();
    $result = $client->get("http://{$request->ES_HOST}:{$request->ES_PORT}", [
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
            'auth' => [$request->ES_LOGIN, $request->ES_PASSWORD],
            'allow_redirects' => false,
        ]);
    $response['status'] = $result->getStatusCode();
    $response['message'] = json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents());
} catch (ConnectException $e) {
    $response['status'] = 404;
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    $response['status'] = $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $response['status'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: In your final `catch()` block, add `print_r($e);` and see what type the exception is.

Comment: there is not a need of your dirty things and all, just check if it hasResponse() if not then it was never sent thus no connection, also the @NigelRen method will work as well

Comment: @NigelRen It gives a ConnectException

Comment: Isn't that what I was suggesting to catch?